# JQuery - Only display pop-up once

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following pop-up displays when the mouse leaves the screen. I need a cookie or something to only display this once (I'm a bit of a novice), but can't work out how to incorporate this into the code.

```
// Exit intent
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}

// Exit intent trigger
addEvent(document, 'mouseout', function(evt) {
    if (evt.toElement == null && evt.relatedTarget == null ) {
        $('.lightbox').slideDown();
    };
});

// Closing the Popup Box
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#close').click(function(){
        $('.lightbox').slideUp();
    });
});
```

You can view the code in action here: http://championcontainersnz.com/buy_estimate

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No cookie.  Just create a global variable `var hasLeftScreen = false;` and then on first leave set it to true.  Add that condition to your ifs.

Comment: Do you want to _never show it again_ or just _once on that page_?

Comment: When popup shows,create a cookie,and later on,just check if cookie exists.

Comment: @Aleksandar your comment is saying what his question is asking. He's asking "how".

Comment: Thanks everyone for your prompt responses. As you can see, there's a lot of different ways to tackle the problem (which I found online), but I can't work out how to incorporate any of these into my code. I can usually dissect code and slot it in myself, but this time I can't work it out. Any example of the new code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example will show you with the code that you have provided. You just need a variable to store if the box has popped up or not.

```js
var isPopped = false;
// Exit intent
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
  if (obj.addEventListener) {
    obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
  } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
    obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
  }
}

// Exit intent trigger
addEvent(document, 'mouseout', function(evt) {
  if (evt.toElement == null && evt.relatedTarget == null && isPopped == false) {
    $('.lightbox').slideDown();
    isPopped = true;
  };
});

// Closing the Popup Box
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#close').click(function() {
    $('.lightbox').slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
.lightbox {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lightbox">Hello There
<button id="close">Close Me</button></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant Jason. It works! Thank you so much for taking the time to provide this answer. Simple, but effective. Well done.

Comment: @N00b Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in jQuery, but the solution could be as easy as creating a window variable.

Define this initally, outside of a function:

```
window.hasPoppedUp = false;
```

On the popup code:

```
if(!window.hasPoppedUp) {
    //do stuff 
    window.hasPoppedUp = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Harry. Sorry to be a pain, but how might I incorporate this code into my original code?